# Can someone figure this subquery problem for me?

Tags: sql

I need to get the expected output but we have to use sub-queries compulsory. I got the expected output without sub-queries but I am just not able to figure out how to get it with sub-queries. 
I have attached the ER diagram and the expected output.

Question Description:
List full details of all types of RD account transactions made by all accounts of customers who are from 'Tamilnadu'. (Use subquery)

Query for expected output without using sub-queries:

```
select bt.*
from bank_transaction bt,bank_rd_account bra, bank_customer bc, bank_cust_contact bcc
where bt.trans_acc_no=bra.account_no
and bra.rd_cust_id=bc.cust_id
and bc.cust_id=bcc.cust_id
and cust_state='Tamilnadu'
order by trans_dt;
```

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWM0T.png)
[ER diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtUyP.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get your requirement correct, this following logic should help you getting your desired output.

> Using appropriate joining is the best option for this purpose. But as you required solve this issue using sub query, you can consider the following sample code.

```
SELECT *
FROM bank_transaction bt
WHERE bt.trans_acc_no IN
(
    SELECT bra.account_no
    FROM bank_rd_account bra
    INNER JOIN bank_customer bc 
        ON bra.rd_cust_id=bc.cust_id
    INNER JOIN bank_cust_contact bcc 
        ON bc.cust_id=bcc.cust_id
        and cust_state='Tamilnadu'
)
```

Comment: You are most welcome @RahulMehta. You can also give me a up vote if it really helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM BANK_TRANSACTION bt  
WHERE bt.TRANS_ACC_NO IN  
(  
  SELECT bra.ACCOUNT_NO  
  FROM BANK_RD_ACCOUNT bra, BANK_CUSTOMER bc  
  WHERE bra.RD_CUST_ID = bc.CUST_ID  
  AND bc.CUST_ID = (SELECT bcc.CUST_ID FROM BANK_CUST_CONTACT bcc    
                    WHERE bcc.CUST_ID = bc.CUST_ID     
                    AND CUST_STATE='Tamilnadu')  
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * FROM bank_transaction t 
WHERE t.trans_acc_no IN(SELECT r.account_no 
        FROM bank_rd_account r, bank_customer c, bank_cust_contact cc 
        WHERE r.rd_cust_id = c.cust_id 
        AND c.cust_id = cc.cust_id 
        AND cc.cust_state = 'Tamilnadu') 
ORDER BY trans_no;
```